# Ideas to bound $\int_{0}^{t}(\int_{0}^{s}f^{2}(r)dr)^{1/2}ds$ from below

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, continuity

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to (0, \infty)$ be a continuous, positive function, such that for some $t > 0$ and some $N \in \mathbb N$, $$\int_{0}^{t}f^{2}(r)dr > N $$

Is it necessarily true that

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_{0}^{s}f^{2}(r)dr\right)^{1/2}ds > N\text{, or larger than any function of }N\text{ ?}
\end{align}

I believe that this may be true, and I need to use continuity in some way, I have attempted things with the Intermediate Value Theorem, etc. but it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $g(r) = f^2(r)$ and $G(s) = \int_0^s g(r) \ \mathrm{d}r$. By hypothesis, $\sqrt{G(t)} > \sqrt{N}$. Therefore by continuity of $\sqrt{G}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\sqrt{G(s)} > \frac{\sqrt{N}}{2}$ for all $s \in [t-\delta, t]$. Consequently,
$$
\int_0^t \sqrt{G(s)}\ \mathrm{d} s \ge \int_{t-\delta}^t \sqrt{G(s)}\ \mathrm{d} s > \int_{t-\delta}^t \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{N} = \frac{1}{2}\delta\sqrt{N}.
$$